# Django login does nothing

Tags: python, django

I'm using django's pre-packaged login, and for some reason, it just refreshes the page, without login in, and without giving me any of the messages I have set in the view.

Here is the html:

```
     <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2" style="background-color: white; margin-top:10px; border-radius: 8px;">
          {% if message %}
          <b>{{message}}</b>  
          {% endif %}           
          <form id="form" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>{{form}}</table>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-2">                   
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
          </form>            
      </div>
```

Here is the url:

```
url(r'^login', 'users.views.login', name='login'),
```

And here the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from deck1.models import Card
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from users.forms import RegisterForm

def login(request):
    message = None
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():         
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    message = "I'm in"
                else:
                    message = "Non active"
            else:
                message = "User or password invalid"
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()                 
    return  render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form, 'message':message}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form's `action` attribute is empty.

Should be: `action="{% url 'login' %}"`.

Comment: Still does nothing  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `"."` in the form's action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just started from scratch another tutorial to make the login, and it works now!, for anyone interested:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html

Not really sure what I was doing wrong, but I found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because of your view's name. you view's name is login and the function you use too login is called login too. so when you use `login(request, user)` it's actually returns to your view not  `django.contrib.auth.login`.
all you have to do is do not use shadow name in you code.
just change the name of your view and it will be work.

```
def login_view(request):
    message = None
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():         
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    message = "I'm in"
                else:
                    message = "Non active"
            else:
                message = "User or password invalid"
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()                 
    return  render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form, 'message':message}, 
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and don't forget to change it in you **urls.py** too.(`url(r'^login', 'users.views.login_view', name='login'),`)